# Windows 7 low performance issue

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, performance, gaming, fps

I am Windows user.So,I have Windows 10 laptop and Windows 7 desktop PC.Here is specs:

### Laptop :

- OS:Windows 10
- CPU: Intel Pentium P6100 2.00GHz
- RAM :4gb(3gb usable)
- GPU: Intel HD Grapichs 2900 (Processor built-in)
- Resolution: 1366x768

---

### Desktop :

- OS:Windows 7
- CPU: Intel Pentium E5300 Dual Core 2.60 GHZ
- RAM :2gb
- GPU: NVIDIA GeForce 7300 SE/7200 GS
- Resolution: 1440x900

Desktop works very well than laptop: Opening programs faster,rendering fast,working 2.5x better than laptop. But not looking this,desktop got lower performance than laptop.For example:I played Counter Strike Source(released at 2005) on both devices and laptop got more performance than desktop. I tested Minecraft and Roblox too but got different results. My laptop couldn't handle Minecraft but got high performance at Roblox. But in desktop results are opposite: I could get 70~80 FPS at Minecraft but got low FPS at Roblox. After this I checked "Rate my PC" function on Windows 7 and here is results:

### Results :

- CPU : 6.1
- RAM : 5.5
- Graphics : 3.5
- Gaming Graphics : 3.2
- Hard Disk : 5.6

I remember that I used this desktop's GPU on other PC and successfully played Call Of Duty: Modern Warfare 4 and Call Of Duty 2: Modern Warfare at 60+ FPS. That desktop got same GPU,same RAM,same resolution.

But why I get low FPS right now and How can I increase my FPS?

Comment: I would start with more ram in the desktop, 2gb is causing it to use the pagefile which will slow everything down. Increase to at least 4gb.

Comment: Uh.... Here is money problem too ;D

Comment: Make and model of desktop?

Comment: Custom made desktop.

Comment: Motherboard make and model?

Comment: @Moab, Made by non-famous company(Simmtronics)

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems that UserBenchmark says that your CPU's are about the same:
https://cpu.userbenchmark.com/Compare/Intel-Pentium-P6100-vs-Intel-Pentium-E5300/m756vsm38

As for your GPU's your laptop performs much better than your Desktop GPU:
https://cpu.userbenchmark.com/Compare/Intel-Pentium-P6100-vs-Intel-Pentium-E5300/m756vsm38

I could not find Intel HD 2900, but I'm assuming it's a typo as 9 is near 0 on the keyboard.

Looking at specs it seems that your laptop would perform better than your PC does. Now windows 10 does perform a bit better than Windows 7, but not too much so. I have no clue how you got 70 fps in minecraft as I got a frame cap of 60 fps on a gt 620 and i7 860 at all low graphics settings. It may be that I am using Java Edition and you have Bedrock edition. Bedrock edition is easier on system resources.

First thing I would change is RAM. Assuming your motherboard has ddr3 you can get 4 or 8gb ram for under $20 on eBay. Make sure to check your motherboard model it may be ddr2 and make sure not to get server memory, it will not work in a desktop. A fresh install of windows (no need to buy a new copy just do the "recover my pc") is not a bad idea, just make sure to back up data and even make a partition for your old files to retrieve them after the install is done. You can get all your game saves data from c:/users/yourusername/appdata/ (usually it is hidden)
I would also check around on eBay or Amazon for a non expensive, but good graphics card.

Since every game runs different you will experience weird things like this with your computers. Frame drops on one and great performance on another.

Roblox needs quite a bit GPU power hence why it worked on your laptop and not desktop. Minecraft is CPU heavy it will also take a bit of RAM.

Hope this bit of info helped! Good luck!